# include primary key value in a procedure while executing the query

Tags: oracle

I am doing a  procedure. called `PRC_CHECKING_PROCEDURE`. The role of this procedure is to do a checking if the row exists.

I have such query: `Insert into tab1 ( code, text) ( 1 ,'test')` code is the primary key.

The procedure role is to do a checking for the above query so the procedure will make it such way :

```
 declare cnt;
 begin
  select count(1) into cnt from tab1  where code = ?? (here is my question how to pass the value)
if count =0 then 
'Insert into tab1 ( code, text) ( 1 ,'test')
end if;
end;
```

**My problem is**  there a way where I can pass the value of the primary key and put in the procedure ?

Comment: You want to check if the code value , you try to insert.. already exist.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primary key constraint prevents duplicates itself. Уou don't need any tricks like above (and moreover they will not work due to transaction isolation) - just handle "dup_val_on_index" exception:

```
SQL> create table t (code int primary key, text varchar2(10))
  2  /

SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> begin
  2   insert into t values(1,'test');
  3  exception
  4   when dup_val_on_index then
  5     dbms_output.put_line('Duplicate !');
  6  end;
  7  /

SQL> /

Duplicate !
```

Comment: can we chat somewhere ? I want to ask you smoething else related to my question ok ?

Comment: yes, can anyone join and give explanation for my question bcz it is bit complicated

Answer (score 0):

Are you just looking for the latest value of the PK? (ie: the largest?)

If so, you can do

```
SELECT COUNT(1) INTO CNT FROM TAB1 WHERE CODE = SELECT MAX(CODE) FROM TAB1
```

Comment: no no it could be random number ... I am looking for the value of the query that I want to do the checking .. understand me ?

Comment: Sorry, no I don't. Could you give a real example?

Comment: I meant chating here in stackover flow .. there is a chat system, anyway i will edit my question